# Run Azure Release Pipeline stage if one of many dependent stages runs

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

We have a rather large deployment surface, say 10 apps that get deployed.  For patch releases we sometimes deploy only one app and I'd like to have a stage run either after all 10 are deployed or if only one is deployed.    A simplified graph looks like the following. The "Do Something" step will only run if all three app stages run and I don't want to have to duplicate it for each app so looking for a better way.  I guess that I could live with it  if it just ran one time on any successful dependent stage (doesn't need to wait for all of them).

[image]

Comment: Is this a YAML Pipeline or a Classic Release?

Comment: The build pipeline is YAML.  The question regarding the release pipeline which was created recently via the UI, I wasn't aware there were two types of release pipelines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think there are a couple options for this. Will need to look at [YAML Multi stage release pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/process/stages?WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5004321). Specifically, [deployment jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/process/deployment-jobs?WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5004321)

First depending on complexity of the "Do something" stage, it could be a [job template](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops&WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5004321#job-reuse) and loaded into each of the app stages. I realize you mentioned you don't want it to run every time so this is just an option.

The second option is if the pipeline is being ran adhoc you will have the ability to select which stages are ran. Thus you could manually select the app stages to run and select the "do something stage" It will look something similar to this. The hard part will be working on the dependencies:

[image]

I'd assumed you'd want the "do something" to be dependent on the success of one of the previous stages.

Answer (score 0):

> Run Azure Release Pipeline stage if one of many dependent stages runs

I am afraidthere is no such out of way to achieve this at this moment.

That is because there is no "OR" syntax for the depend on. And we could not add the condition for the depend on.

You could submit this request condition "OR" to our UserVoice site (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21 ), which is our main forum for product suggestions. Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps.

**As workaround**:

**The main idea of the solution is**: You could try to set depend on for the stage Secure with `[]`, then add a Inline powershell task before other tasks. This task will call the REST API [Definitions - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/definitions/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) to monitor whether all the stages in the current release pipeline have inprocess and queue states. If so, wait for 30 seconds, and then loop again until all other stages in the current release pipeline have no inprocess and queue states. Then next execute other tasks will be executed.

You could check my [previous ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65815516/is-it-possible-to-run-a-final-stage-in-azure-pipelines-without-knowing-how-man) for detailed info: