# Is it possible to make the pass/fail status of an Azure pipeline dependent of the pass/fail status of a downstream pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm currently migrating code from Gitlab to Azure DevOps and Azure Pipelines. In Gitlab I have a two repo setup like this:

> - Pipeline A in repo 1 runs build & UTs. It triggers:
> - Pipeline B in repo 2 runs solution tests. If it passes:
> - Pipeline A publishes artifacts

You can do this in Gitlab using a [depend strategy](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/multi_project_pipelines.html#mirror-status-of-a-triggered-pipeline-in-the-trigger-job) in your trigger job. This means that if Pipeline B fails, Pipeline A also fails, and so the publishing stage in Pipeline A is skipped.

Am I right in thinking that this setup is not natively supported in Azure Pipelines, e.g. with [pipeline completion triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/pipeline-triggers?view=azure-devops)? I don't think you can have one pipeline pausing half way through and waiting for another, or have the upstream pipeline's pass/fail status mirror that of the downstream pipeline.

If so, what do you think would be a good solution here? Is it possible to gate PR Build Validation on the downstream pipeline, so if pipeline A passed on repo 1's branch X but pipeline B failed, Azure wouldn't let me merge branch X?

I've had a couple of ideas for hacky workarounds if this isn't supported:

> 1. Write a script in pipeline A that kicks off pipeline B, sleeps and periodically polls the API to check whether pipeline B has
>    passed/failed
> 2. Checkout repo 2's code during pipeline A, and run the solution tests there

Do either of them sound sensible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to make the pass/fail status of an Azure pipeline
> dependent of the pass/fail status of a downstream pipeline?

There is no such out of box way to achieve this at this moment.

Personally, your ideas are sound. I have encountered similar requests before, but it was about release, but the concept of their implementation is the same.

The main idea is：

1. Add a powershell task to Pipeline A to call the REST API to queue pipeline B, 2. Cyclically monitor the construction results of pipeline B.
2. After getting the result of pipeline B, call the log command according to the result of pipeline B.
3. To set the construction result of pipeline A.

You could checkmy previous thread for some more details:

[Is it possible to run a "final stage" in Azure Pipelines without knowing how many stages there are in total?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65815516/is-it-possible-to-run-a-final-stage-in-azure-pipelines-without-knowing-how-man/65821917#65821917)

And the [log command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash#complete-finish-timeline) set the build result:

```
##vso[task.complete result=Failed;]DONE
```