# scheduled task in release pipeline that runs every x minutes

Tags: azure-devops, deployment, devops, release, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Working on a deployment scenario where I need to make a REST call to verify some values for my deployment every x minutes. If anyone knows of a way to achieve this, it would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe this is also an option: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/monitor-web-app-availability

Comment: We dont use Azure monitors in our org unfortunately :(

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Is there any update for this issue? Feel free to let me know if the answer could give you some help. Just a reminder of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

> scheduled task in release pipeline that runs every x minutes

If you want to verify some values in current release pipeline for every x minutes, you could try to use the REST API to monitor those values:

You could refer [my previous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65815516/is-it-possible-to-run-a-final-stage-in-azure-pipelines-without-knowing-how-man/65821917#65821917) for some more details.

And if you could verify some values in other build pipeline, you could set the `schedules` for the pipeline:

```
schedules:
- cron: "x * * * *"
  displayName: Daily midnight build
  branches:
    include:
    - main
```

You could chek the document [Cron syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/scheduled-triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#cron-syntax) for some more details.